# Why it is not possible to do 2 - A , where A is a matrix and 2 a natural number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I know that to subtract two matrices we need them to have the same number of rows and columns, and I also know that it is not possible to subtract a natural number from a matrix, but I don't know why it is not possible

Comment: Well, what would it be?

Comment: A natural number is a $1$ by $1$ matrix!

Comment: Sometimes, people compute $2-A$ as $2I-A$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ok I think I got it

Comment: @MichaelBurr is the I the identity matrix?

Comment: @mark.aurelio Yes - it has $1$s on the diagonal and $0$s everywhere else.

Comment: Isn't it somehow intuitive that you can only add or subtract objects from the same category?

Comment: $2 - A$ is undefined. You can give it any meaning you want though. Your question is why is it undefined? Well, it is undefined since most people can not come up with a meaningful definition for $2 - A$.

Comment: Friedrich Philipp You can add a real and an integer with each other, although they do not belong to the same type.

Comment: @Pedro but they are of the same type, they are both real numbers.  In the context of adding an integer to a real number, we implicitly think of the integer as a real number for that specific context and use the definition of addition for real numbers in the calculation.

Comment: @JMoravitz Integers and real numbers are **not of the same type**. They are represented in a total different way, other operations are defined on them, $\ldots$ .

Comment: @Pedro when you tell me that you want to compute $2+\sqrt{2}$, I will not in my mind think of $2$ as in integer in this situation, I will think of it as a real number.  Why would I choose to ignore the fact that $2$ is a real number just to prove a point?  I know how to add two real numbers together, it is well defined using dedekind cuts.  There is no reason for me to restrict myself to explicitly thinking of $2$ as $\{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$ in this context when it doesn't benefit me to do so.  That the concept of $2$ is present in multiple contexts is besides the point.

Comment: @JMoravitz In my mind I think of the first $2$ as an integer, unless otherwise stated. In that case I will see that an integer is added to a root of an integer. The root, which acts as a function, of an integer is not calculatable so the integer there is promoted to a real. Then we still have to add $2 + "$a real$"$ which again lets to my $2$ in the expression being promoted to a real. They are not of the same type if I needed to do promotions. (cfr. type theory)